# After adding custom price to product currency is not converting on cart page

Tags: magento-1, custom-prices

To add custom price while adding to cart I have used catalog_product_load_after observer and used the function to add price.

```
public function checkoutCartProductAddAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) 
{
    $newPrice = 200;
    $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
    $item->setCustomPrice($newPrice);
    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($newPrice);
    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);

}
```

this is working fine for changing the price. But if I change currency on cart page currency is not changing properly. Any solutions??

Comment: You can try this solution, it's working for me : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37827188/magento-custom-price-value-not-converting-by-changing-currency

Comment: @NitinVala I have tried the same before but not worked for me.

Comment: Have you got the solution for this ?